# UITableViewAutomaticDimension return -1

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Hi I make tableviewcontroller class and I want to get cell height dynamicly so i use UITableViewAutomaticDimension but it always return me -1.

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    println("\(tableView.rowHeight)")
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

when I do tableView.rowHeight = 44 everything works great. My superclass is UIViewController.

Comment: have you added constraints to your cell?

Comment: No, I will add it and write the result It helps thanks !

Comment: The value of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is not documented, but under the hood it is equal to -1. It is used as a signal to `UITableView` that it should find the cells’ height using `-systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for footer/header height and only if you implement:

```
- tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
```

If you're implementing the:

```
- tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```

it will not work. `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is not intended to be used to set the row height. Use `rowHeight` and specify your value or implement:

```
- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: Comments to my question have a good answer, we are talking about swift not obj-c

Comment: @Bearwithme: is this statement still accurate? * UITableViewAutomaticDimension is not intended to be used to set the row height*

Comment: @SwiftArchitect no it is not accurate anymore. `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is also used for row heights now.