# UITableView bug in iOS8 when selecting items with estimatedHeight different from rowHeight

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I am working on a project that is both iOS7 and iOS8. And I ran into this bug on iOS8, where the tableview will "jump" when selecting an item.

This bug is only there when estimated height is set and it differs from the row height.

Here are two gifs of the same code in iOS8 and iOS7. First iOS8:

[image: TableView in iOS8]

And now in iOS7:

[image: TableView in iOS7]

I have made a sample project showing the bug here: https://github.com/bjarkehs/TableViewiOS8Bug

I am not sure if I am simply missing something, but I am stuck with this issue and I haven't been able to find anything on this.

Here are my tableView methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 1) {
        return 30;
    }
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld", @"Wat", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 45.f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50.f;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[UIViewController new] animated:YES];
}
```

Here is an example viewcontroller where the calculated height is not hardcoded, showing the same issue:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    NSMutableArray *_items;
    CGFloat _estimatedHeight;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    _estimatedHeight = 70.f;

    CGFloat randomOffset = 30.f;

    _items = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *tempItems = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSInteger j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
            NSInteger offset = arc4random_uniform(randomOffset);
            [tempItems addObject:@(_estimatedHeight + (randomOffset/2) - offset)];
        }
        [_items addObject:tempItems];
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 1) {
        return 30;
    }
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld", @"Wat", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return _estimatedHeight;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [[[_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[UIViewController new] animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: You might need to post your tableview methods here.

Comment: Yeah, I might as well. The tableview methods are there now.

Comment: Maybe I'm retarded but I can't see any difference between 7 and 8. What's the exact problem?

Comment: The selected cell is "Wat 5". On iOS7 when you come back from the other viewcontroller it is at the same position, on iOS8 it has "jumped" up.

Comment: From the docs : _Providing an estimate the height of rows can improve the user experience when loading the table view. If the table contains variable height rows, it might be expensive to calculate all their heights and so lead to a longer load time. Using estimation allows you to defer some of the cost of geometry calculation from load time to scrolling time._ So if incorrect height is given it might give un expected results as you have observed.

Answer (score -1):

Your implementation for Estimated Height For At Index isn't something I've seen before. Have a look at this where I detailed using this pattern...

[Estimated Height Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156295/uitableview-choppy-scrolling-without-images-or-content-fetching/26162791#26162791)

Comment: This is just a sample project. I'm merely showing you the simplest case, where the estimated height is not equal to the actual height of the cell. The actual height can be anything from let's say 40 to 60 pixels, but implementing that in the sample project would only add to more complexity without adding to the example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but estimate height works on the principles you create a 'prototype' cell configure it's and it's subviews properties (labels, positions etc) then obtain the height. Your example has hardcoded values giving no real advantage BUT, making the table behave strange.

Comment: On top of that you have hardcoded the height which just negates any estimated calculations

Comment: In your example you have a hardcoded estimated height. Same as in this project. In the real project I have some code that calculates the height based on the stuff I put in my cells, meaning the height will never be static. I have hardcoded the height as a value larger than the estimated, since it is a very likely scenario that the cell is higher. The estimated height is based on an average scenario, but the cell can both be taller and smaller than the estimated height. This should not matter, since it's a rough estimate meant to be fast.

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation. It's not a magic bullet that does your heights for you. Estimated is just that, what you estimate the majority of the cells to be. Mine comes from IB based on the default height fully populated. I have shown you how to use this pattern but you keep arguing that it's not what you have. You can either implement it as I have done and shown or good luck making it do more than it can.

Comment: "In your example you have a hardcoded estimated height. " - In my example height for row is calculated yours isn't - doesn't that give you a clue?

Comment: I'm not trying to make it do more. I'm merely showing that the code works in iOS7, but not in iOS8. I promise it is according to the documentation. The hardcoded height is simply to show that a height different from the estimated causes unwanted behaviour in iOS8 but not in iOS7. I am merely making the simplest possible example project I can to illustrate the problem. I could have it randomly calculate heights for all the items with +/-5 pixels from the estimated height, which would show the same thing. But I'm not sure how that is relevant?

Comment: " But I'm not sure how that is relevant?" - For me that's your problem - you haven't shown height for row, you keep saying you have put in hardcoded values to illustrate your point. You clearly don't understand how this works. Height for row need to be calculated (yours isn't even present) estimated is for the system to begin laying out, yours uses this value but as the two values aren't the same there will be issues. I can't be clearer than that. if it works in iOS 7 it's no by design. If you think you can whack a few height floats and it work - it won't.

Comment: I have now updated my question with code that does not use a hardcoded height, which still has the same unintended behaviour.

Comment: @latenitecoder if you read what he says, the original project contains code to calculate the height using a sizing cell like your link illustrates. Then ,my guess, he has boiled it down to that iOS8 fails whenever the calculated height is different than the estimated height.

Comment: @mbogh - He hasn't shown how this is calculated, crucial. I noticed it has been updated to show a value plucked from an array of arrays.